# Add to cart in FormsView instead of DetailsView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net

Currently I have my product details page displayed in FormView which looks as follows:

[image]

I have this chunk of codes for the add to cart button but it is for DetailsView. How do I modify the codes to work for FormView?

```
protected void btnBuy_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // test to remind customer to login first
    if ((string)Session["sFlag"] != "T")
    {
        Type csType = this.GetType();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorLogin);
    }
    else
    {
        OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
        mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source="
        + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TabStoreDB.mdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        //insert item purchased to itemsTable
        int intOrderNo = (int)Session["sOrderNo"];
        DetailsViewRow row0 = DetailsView1.Rows[0]; // Rows[0] contains the productId
        String strProductId = row0.Cells[1].Text;
        DetailsViewRow row6 = DetailsView1.Rows[6]; // Rows[6] contains the unit price
        String strUnitPrice = row6.Cells[1].Text;
        float floUnitPrice = float.Parse(strUnitPrice);
        String strQty = DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        int intQty = int.Parse(strQty);
        string strSQL = "INSERT INTO itemsTable(iOrderNo, iProductId, iQty, iUnitPrice)"
        + "VALUES (@OrderNo, @ProductId, @Qty, @UnitPrice)";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, mDB);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNO", intOrderNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", strProductId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", intQty);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", floUnitPrice);
        mDB.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mDB.Close();
        Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
    }
}
```

FormView Codes:

```
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ProductDetails" Runat="Server">
<asp:FormView ID="FormView_Product" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID" 

    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" Height="296px" Width="223px" 
    style="margin-right: 0px">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <table id="Table_01" width="770" height="745" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="5" align="center">
        <img src='<%# Eval("ProductUrl") %>' width="238" height="243" 
                        alt='<%# Eval("ProductModel") %>' /></td></td>
    <td rowspan="7">
        <img src="images/productdetails_03.jpg" width="1" height="705" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="7" valign="top">
        <br /><br /><%# Eval("ProductID") %><span class="productname-text"><%# Eval("ProductBrand") %> <%# Eval("ProductModel") %></span>
        <br /> <span class="style1">Our Price:</span> <span class="price-text">S$<%# Eval("NormalPrice") %></span>
        <br /><span class="description-text"><%# Eval("ProductDetails") %></span>   
        </td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <img src="images/productdetails_05.jpg" width="196" height="98" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/productdetails_06.jpg" width="1" height="42" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/productdetails_07.jpg" width="195" height="41" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/productdetails_08.jpg" width="195" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="images/productdetails_09.jpg" width="7" height="94" alt=""></td>
    <td background="images/productdetails_10.jpg" valign="top">

        <br />
        <span class="quantity-text">&nbsp;&nbsp; Quantity:</span>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btnBuy" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl="~/images/addtocartbutton.jpg" />

    <td>
        <img src="images/productdetails_11.jpg" width="7" height="94" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/productdetails_12.jpg" width="196" height="471" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img alt='<%# Eval("ProductModel") %>' border="0" 
                  src='<%# Eval("ProductUrl") %>' style="height: 83px; width: 83px" /><img 
                  alt='<%# Eval("ProductModel") %>' border="0" src='<%# Eval("ProductUrl") %>' 
                  style="height: 83px; width: 83px" /><img alt='<%# Eval("ProductModel") %>' 
                  border="0" src='<%# Eval("ProductUrl") %>' style="height: 83px; width: 83px" /></td></td>
</tr>
```

Edited codes

```
 protected void btnBuy_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
        // test to remind customer to login first
        if ((string)Session["sFlag"] != "T")
        {
            Type csType = this.GetType();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorLogin);
        }
        else
        {
            OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
            mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source="
            + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TabStoreDB.mdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd;
            //insert item purchased to itemsTable
            int intOrderNo = (int)Session["sOrderNo"];

            FormViewRow row0 = FormView_Product.Row;
            String strProductId = ((Label)row0.FindControl("ProductID")).Text;
            Int32 unitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row0.FindControl("NormalPrice")).Text);
            String strUnitPrice = ((Label)row0.FindControl("NormalPrice")).Text;
            float floUnitPrice = float.Parse(strUnitPrice);
            DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            String strQty = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            int intQty = int.Parse(strQty);
            string strSQL = "INSERT INTO itemsTable(iOrderNo, iProductId, iQty, iUnitPrice)"
            + "VALUES (@OrderNo, @ProductId, @Qty, @UnitPrice)";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, mDB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNO", intOrderNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", strProductId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", intQty);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", floUnitPrice);
            mDB.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mDB.Close();
            Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
```

Comment: Don't use subject line for tags. Tag line is for that.

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines

```
DetailsViewRow row0 = DetailsView1.Rows[0]; // Rows[0] contains the productId
String strProductId = row0.Cells[1].Text;
DetailsViewRow row6 = DetailsView1.Rows[6]; // Rows[6] contains the unit price
```

To

```
FormViewRow row0 = FormView_Product.Row;
String strProductId = ((Label)row0.FindControl("lblProductId")).Text;
Int32 unitPrice =Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row0.FindControl("lblUnitPrice")).Text);
```

Comment: That assumes his DetailsView and his FormView have the same definition for a row, and I'm not sure that would necessarily be the case.

Comment: My FormView ID is FormView_Product so I've changed it from DetailsView1.Rows[0] to FormView_Product.Rows[0] but I am getting an error "does not contain a definition for Rows". Did i defined it wrongly?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar - I'm still not convinced.  What I'm saying is what if the columns/fields in his FormView row are different than the DetailView?  The two controls serve distinctly different purposes, as I understand it.  You seem to be making a blanket statement that, while it may technically be accurate, is dangerous.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar Yeap did exactly what you posted. Still getting the "does not contain a definition for Rows" for the "Rows" line :/

Comment: @Aurelio; I have just checked at my end and there was problem in previous code, I have just update the new one. You have to go in this way.

Comment: Does this line need to be changed as well?
    String strUnitPrice = row6.Cells[1].Text;
"The name row6 does not exist in the current context"

Comment: yes, you need to change that one as well. Follow the way I have defined in my answer.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar I've tried the above recommendations but it doesn't seem to work. Could you take a look at my codes and the FormView codes above?

Comment: @aurelio - The code snippet above is looking for controls that don't exist in your posted markup.  I've added an answer that extends Muhammad's that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad's code is the right direction to go, but the reason it won't work for you is you do not have any controls with the specified ID's in the FormViewRow.  Try the following:

First, Add Label controls to your markup for ProductID and NormalPrice, named lblProductID and lblNormalPrice:

```
<td rowspan="7" valign="top">
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblProductID" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' runat="sever" />
    <span class="productname-text"><%# Eval("ProductBrand") %> <%# Eval("ProductModel") %></span>
    <br />
    <span class="style1">Our Price:</span>
    <asp:Label ID="lblNormalPrice" CssClass="price-text" Text='<%# Eval("S$" + "NromalPrice") %>' runat="server" />
    <br />
    <span class="description-text"><%# Eval("ProductDetails") %></span>
</td>
```

Now your code should work, but I'd change a couple of things (reason for the change in comments):

```
FormViewRow row0 = FormView_Product.Row;
string strProductId = ((Label)row0.FindControl("lblProductID")).Text;
// Use TryParse in place of Parse; if the string is not parseable it will return false
float unitPrice;
float floUnitPrice = float.TryParse(((Lable)row0.FindControl("lblNormalPrice")).Text, out unitPrice) ? unitPrice : 0;
// Use SelectedItem.Text instead of SelectedValue, as I didn't see any settings for Value in your markup, which might result in a blank string.
int quantity;
int intQty = int.TryParse(((DropDownList)row0.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedItem.Text, out quantity) ? quantity : 0;
```